# Solving nonlinear ODE with boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear, boundary-conditions

I am trying to solve the below fucntions using a NDsolve, but I can't get the the converges of them at the certain initial variables.I'm using Mathematica 11.3. I appreciate any help.

```
Z=800;
g= 0.023800000000000000000;
k2= 0.000194519;
R= 1.5472;
ytest0= -13.911917694213733`;
ϵ = $MachineEpsilon ;
y1[ytest_?NumericQ] := 
    NDSolve[
      {y''[r] + 2 y'[r]/r == k2 Sinh[y[r]] , y[1] == ytest, 
       y'[ϵ] == 0}, y, {r, ϵ, 1}, 
       Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", "NonstiffTest" -> False}];
 y2[ytest_?NumericQ] := 
   NDSolve[
     {y''[r] + 2 y'[r]/r == κ2 Sinh[y[r]], 
      y[1] == ytest, y'[R] == 0}, y, {r, 1, R}, 
      Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", "NonstiffTest" -> False}];
y1Try[ytest_?NumericQ] := y'[1] /. y1[ytest];
y2Try[ytest_?NumericQ] := y'[1] /. y2[ytest];
f = ytest /. FindRoot[y1Try[ytest] - y2Try[ytest]==-Zg, {ytest, ytest0}]
```

Comment: @zhk In the way that _every_ ODE is also a PDE... ;)

Comment: [Cross Post](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1458395)

Comment: The discontinuity `Z/g` in `y'[r]` at `r == 1` is enormous.  Are you sure that this value is correct?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quantity `κ2` in the question is undefined.  However, the cross-posting identified by [Mariusz Iwaniuk](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/26828/mariusz-iwaniuk) in a comment above suggests that `k2` actually is meant. With this change, the computation is equivalent to solving the ODE, `{y''[r] + 2 y'[r]/r == k2 Sinh[y[r]], y'[R] == 0, y'[ϵ] == 0}` with a discontinuity in `y'[r]` equal to `Z g` at `r == 1`.  With this modification to the ODE, it can be recast as

```
Z = 800; g = Rationalize[0.0238, 0];
k2 = Rationalize[ 0.000194519, 0];
ϵ = 10^-4; R = Rationalize[1.5472, 0];
ps = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y''[r] + 2 y'[r]/r == k2 Sinh[y[r]], 
    y[ϵ] == y0, y'[ϵ] == 0, WhenEvent[r == 1, y'[r] -> y'[r] + Z g]}, {y, y'}, 
    {r, ϵ, R}, {y0}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", WorkingPrecision -> 30];
sol = FindRoot[Last[ps[y0]][R], {y0, -11.25, -11.}, Evaluated -> False][[1, 2]]
(* -11.1979 *)

Plot[First[ps[sol]][r], {r, ϵ, R}, AxesLabel -> {r, y}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, Medium}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Last[ps[sol]][r], {r, ϵ, R}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {r, y'}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, Medium}]
```

[image]

The computation takes only seconds.

**Addendum**

In response to a comment below, the solution for `k2 = Rationalize[0.05716690559951900467, 0];` is

```
sol = Quiet@FindRoot[Last[ps[y0]][R], {y0, -12, 0}, Evaluated -> False][[1, 2]]
(* -5.51467 *)
```

The corresponding plot of `y` looks very much like that above but shifted approximately by the shift in `y0`.

[image]

The corresponding plot of `y'` also looks very much like that above.  Note that the `FindRoot` search range has been expanded in this computation, and `Quiet` has been prepended to avoid printing the numerous errors that `FindRoot` encounters before finding the correct answer.

**Second Addendum**

Varying `k2`, as requested by the OP in a comment below, is accomplished as follows.

```
psk = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y''[r] + 2 y'[r]/r == k Sinh[y[r]], 
     y[ϵ] == y0, y'[ϵ] == 0, WhenEvent[r == 1, y'[r] -> y'[r] + Z g]}, {y, y'}, 
     {r, ϵ, R}, {y0, k}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", WorkingPrecision -> 30];
ytablog = Table[{Exp[k], Quiet@FindRoot[Last[psk[y0, Exp[k]]][R], {y0, -12, 0}, 
    Evaluated -> False][[1, 2]]}, {k, -9, 0, 1/10}];
ListLogLinearPlot[ytablog, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, AxesLabel -> {k2, y[0]}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, Medium}]
```

[image]

A rough fit to this curve is `Log[k2] - 2.655`.  Varying `R` can be accomplished in a similar manner.

Interestingly, varying `R` between `5/4` and `2` has minimal effect on the plot just above.  Below are plots of `y[r]` for `R = Range[5/4,2,1/4]` - `{"Blue", "Orange", "Green", "Red"}`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you bbgodfrey, There is a mistake in my code the discontinuity (Zg) in y'[r] at r == 1 not (Z/g) sorry for that. From that, I am looking for discontinuity in region [20 to 30], when using your way for 23 given me a wrong result even though  any values from 5 to 25 gave a wrong result.So, I am not sure that (28) number comes from where? it should be based on the initial values. Does it come from multiply (Z by g)?

Comment: @user60211  I used 28, because it yielded a value of `y[1]` approximately equal to your `ytest0`.  Rerunning the code with 19.04 is easy, but it is very late here.  I shall do so tomorrow morning.  By the way, what do you mean by "wrong result" in your comment?

Comment: I meant the graph is not reasonable. I am looking for something similar what you got for 28. Ok I am waiting you and thanks for your help.

Comment: @user60211  Redoing the computation and modifying my answer for  `Z g` instad of `28` did not take long.  I hope it meets your need.

Comment: very nice! I got what I want. Thank you so much. Last question if I increase the k2 value let say k2 = 0.05716690559951900467 my code is not running. Can you help me in that. By the way, Can I plot the data from 0 to 1?

Comment: @user60211 I have added the solution for your requested value of k2. I imagine that solutions from `k2 == 0` to `k2 == 1` can be obtained, although with greater difficulty as `k2` is approaches `0`. What data do you wish to plot over that range?

Comment: My goal is to plot the First[ps[sol]][r] for different values of k2 {0.03 to 1}, and R {1.1 to 2} and then see the behavior of the solution. Again thank you so much.

Comment: k2  range is {0.03 to 0.2} *

Comment: @user60211  The `k2` plot has been added.  Varying `R` can be done in a similar manner.  If my answer meets your expectations, please do not forget to accept it.

Comment: Thank you! I have a couples of points regarding your code: How did you get the initial value that inside the find root {-12,0}, also I tried to run your code without using rationalize command, but did not work so what the principle idea behind using rationalize command. In the find root, what Last[ps[y0]][R] command do?could you gives more details?

Comment: @user60211 I chose  `{-12, 0}` to be broad enough to bracket expected values of `y0`.  `WorkingPrecision -> 30` requires that constants have precision at least as large as `30`, and `Rationalize` accomplishes this.  `Last[ps[y0]][R]` is the numerically computed value of `y'[R]` for a given `y0`.  Check the documentation of `ParametricNDSolve` for details.

Comment: In your code @bbgodfrey, for checking the Z is equal 800, I used this code ' 4 \[Pi] n0
  NIntegrate[(r^2) (Evaluate[
      Exp[-y[r] /. ps[r]]])[[1]], {r, \[Epsilon], 
   R}](* should equla Z=800 *), however, it did not give me 800?!! n0 here is equal 0.000146543

Comment: The code in your comment contains several errors.  But, even if it did not, I do no see why the answer should b `Z`.

Comment: Because integrate over {0 to R} region has to give Z.

Comment: The correct integral, I believe, is `k2 NIntegrate[r^2 Sinh[-First[ps[sol]][r]], {r, ϵ, R}]`, which should be equal to `Z g`, and it is.

Comment: I have appreciated your answer. Thank you so much @bbgodfrey. You've already been very helpful.

Comment: would you please explain to me what is this line doing exactly FindRoot[Last[ps[y0]][R], {y0, -12, 0}, Evaluated -> False][[1, 2]], is  Evaluated -> False][[1, 2]] and 1 , 2 refer to y, y' ? also {y0,-12,0} means your initial guess of y0 on the region of (-12,0) or not?

Comment: Finally, If I Change the equation limit say ps = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y''[r] + 2 y'[r]/r == k2 Sinh[y[r]], 
    y[ϵ] == y0, y'[ϵ] == 0, WhenEvent[r == a, y'[r] -> y'[r] + Z g]}, {y, y'}, 
    {r, ϵ, 1}, {y0}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", WorkingPrecision -> 30];
sol = FindRoot[Last[ps[y0]][1], {y0, -11.25, -11.}, Evaluated -> False][[1, 2]] where a=15, how could I figure out the best region for y0? I appreciate your help.

Comment: `r == 15` does not fall within the domain of integration and, therefore, does not trigger `WhenEvent`.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Forget to mention that a is unit of R so a= 15/R.

Comment: Although `R` does not appear in the code of your recent comment, I presume that its value is `1`, because earlier `R` was the upper limit of integration.  If so, then your last comment indicates that `a = 15` and still is not within the domain of integration.