# DSolve, NDSolve with WhenEvent Give Incorrect Solution for Simple ODE

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, bugs, nonlinear

**NDSolve Results**

On the course of addressing [question 181974](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/182015/1063), I encountered the following problem.

```
k2 = Rationalize[ 0.000194519, 0];
ϵ = 10^-4;
R = Rationalize[1.5472, 0];
s = NDSolveValue[{y''[r] + 2 y'[r]/r == k2 Sinh[y[r]], y'[R] == 0, y'[ϵ] == 0, 
    WhenEvent[r == 1, y'[r] -> y'[r] + 1]}, {y, y'}, {r, ϵ, R}, 
    Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {y[ϵ] == 
    Rationalize[-8.9941, 0], y'[ϵ] == 0}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 30];
Plot[First[s][r], {r, ϵ, R}, AxesLabel -> {r, y}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, Medium}]
```

[image]

which visibly is incorrect, because `y'[R] == 0` is far from being satisfied.  Moreover, this error is robust in that `NDSolve` yields the same solution for all credible initial guesses for `y[ϵ]` that I have tried.  Interestingly, `y[ϵ] == 0`, as in the plot, would be correct, if the jump condition in `y'[r]` at `r == 1` were not included.  So, my question is, have I made an error?  And, if not, is this a bug?  For completeness, the correct solution is

```
ps = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y''[r] + 2 y'[r]/r == k2 Sinh[y[r]], 
    y[ϵ] == y0, y'[ϵ] == 0, WhenEvent[r == 1, y'[r] -> y'[r] + 1]}, {y, y'}, 
    {r, ϵ, R}, {y0}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", WorkingPrecision -> 30];
sol = FindRoot[Last[ps[y0]][R], {y0, -9, -8.8}, Evaluated -> False][[1, 2]]
(* -8.99411 *)
Plot[First[ps[sol]][r], {r, ϵ, R}, AxesLabel -> {r, y}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, Medium}]
```

[image]

**Addendum: DSolve Results**

In comments below, [Alex Trounov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/58388/alex-trounev) observed that `NDSolve` also gives an incorrect result for the linearized version of the ODE, `y''[r] + 2 y'[r]/r == k2 y[r]`.  (The plotted result is nearly identical to the first figure above.)  For completeness, the correct result is

[image]

The linearized ODE also can be solved symbolically, and I have done so.

```
DSolveValue[{y''[r] + 2 y'[r]/r == k2 y[r], y'[R] == 0, y'[0] == 0, 
    WhenEvent[r == 1, y'[r] -> y'[r] + 1]}, y[r], {r, 0, R}]
(* Piecewise[{{0, 0 <= r <= 1}, {(5000*Sqrt[10/1151]*(-E^((13*Sqrt[1151/10])/5000)
   + E^((13*Sqrt[1151/10]*r)/5000)))/(13*E^((13*Sqrt[1151/10]*(1 + r))/10000)*r), 
   Inequality[1, Less, r, LessEqual, 967/625]}}, Indeterminate] *)
```

Plotting this expression again yields a plot nearly identical to the first one in this question.  In other words, `DSolve` also yields the same wrong answer!  To obtain the correct symbolic answer, begin by noting that the solution of the ODE without boundary conditions is of the form, `c1 Sinh[Sqrt[k] r]/r + c2 Cosh[Sqrt[k] r]/r`, as can be verified by,

```
Simplify[(y''[r] + 2 y'[r]/r == k y[r]) /. y -> 
    Function[r, c1 Sinh[Sqrt[k] r]/r + c2 Cosh[Sqrt[k] r]/r], k > 0]
(* True *)
```

The solution for `0 < r < 1` must be

```
fm[r_] = c1 Sinh[Sqrt[k] r]/r
```

so that it is not singular at the origin.  The solution for  `1 < r < rmax` is

```
fp[r_] = c3 Sinh[Sqrt[k] r]/r + c4 Cosh[Sqrt[k] r]/r
```

Applying matching conditions at `r == 1` and the `y'[rmax] == 0` outer boundary condition determines the three coefficients.

```
sc = Solve[{fm[1] == fp[1], fm'[1] + 1 == fp'[1], fp'[rmax] == 0}, 
    {c1, c3, c4}] // Simplify // Flatten
(* {c1 -> (-Sqrt[k] rmax Cosh[Sqrt[k] (-1 + rmax)] + Sinh[Sqrt[k] (-1 + rmax)])
       /(k rmax Cosh[Sqrt[k] rmax] - Sqrt[k] Sinh[Sqrt[k] rmax]), 
    c3 -> (Sinh[Sqrt[k]] (Cosh[Sqrt[k] rmax] - Sqrt[k] rmax Sinh[Sqrt[k] rmax]))
       /(-k rmax Cosh[Sqrt[k] rmax] + Sqrt[k] Sinh[Sqrt[k] rmax]), 
    c4 -> -(Sinh[Sqrt[k]]/Sqrt[k])} *)
```

Consequently, the complete symbolic solution is

```
sa = Piecewise[{{fm[r], r < 1}, {fp[r], r > 1}}] /. sc /. {rmax -> R, k -> k2}
```

which is a bit long to reproduce here.  Plotting it yields a figure identical to that immediately above.  In conclusion, neither `DSolve` nor `NDSolve` is able to solve this relatively simple problem, in both cases returning essentially the same wrong answer.  Certainly, this is a bug.  I would welcome the perspectives of others.

Comment: In your case, ODE is non-linear, but I checked that the same error remains for the linear equation `s = NDSolve[{y''[r] + 2 y'[r]/r == k2*y[r], y'[R] == 0, 
    y'[\[Epsilon]] == 0, 
    WhenEvent[{r == 1, y'[r] < 0}, y'[r] -> y'[r] + 1]}, 
   y, {r, \[Epsilon], R}, 
   Method -> {"Shooting", 
     "StartingInitialConditions" -> {y[\[Epsilon]] == 
        Rationalize[-8.9941, 0], y'[\[Epsilon]] == 0}, 
     Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]'

Comment: You can remove all methods and solve a linear equation `y''[r] + 2 y'[r]/r == k2 y[r]`, there remains a similar error. It seems that the boundary condition `y'[R] == 0` is ignored in combination with `WhenEvent`,