# Combined ParametricNDSolveValue with Do loop?

Tags: differential-equations, infinite-loop

two weeks ago, I post a question [see](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/181974/60211), and I got its answer, however, I would like to vary the values: g from (0.02 to 0.07), R from (0.1 to 0.3),and k2 from (0.03 to 0.07)  by an increment of 0.01 using for Do loop. Can you please help?

Comment: And what do you need to get out of the loop?

Comment: I want to see the behavior of y' and y?

Comment: How do you want to visualize data - on a plane or in space?

Comment: I want to  visualize data  on a plane.

Comment: A set of curves on one plane or each curve on one plane?

Comment: Does not matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use the following model for parametric studies.

```
p[Z0_, g0_, k0_, R0_] := Block[{Z = Z0, g = Rationalize[g0, 0],
       k2 = Rationalize[k0, 0],
       \[Epsilon] = 10^-4, R = Rationalize[R0, 0]},
      ps = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y''[r] + 2 y'[r]/r == k2 Sinh[y[r]], 
         y[\[Epsilon]] == y0, y'[\[Epsilon]] == 0, 
         WhenEvent[r == 1, y'[r] -> y'[r] + Z g]}, {y, 
         y'}, {r, \[Epsilon], R}, {y0}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", 
        WorkingPrecision -> 20];
      sol = FindRoot[Last[ps[y0]][R], {y0, -1}, 
         Evaluated -> False][[1, 2]]; 
      Plot[First[ps[sol]][r], {r, \[Epsilon], R}, AxesLabel -> {r, y}, 
       PlotLabel -> 
        Grid[{{"Z", "g", "k2", "R"}, {Z0, g0, k0, R0}}, Frame -> All]]]

    p1[Z0_, g0_, k0_, R0_] := Block[{Z = Z0, g = Rationalize[g0, 0],
       k2 = Rationalize[k0, 0],
       \[Epsilon] = 10^-4, R = Rationalize[R0, 0]},
      ps = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y''[r] + 2 y'[r]/r == k2 Sinh[y[r]], 
         y[\[Epsilon]] == y0, y'[\[Epsilon]] == 0, 
         WhenEvent[r == 1, y'[r] -> y'[r] + Z g]}, {y, 
         y'}, {r, \[Epsilon], R}, {y0}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", 
        WorkingPrecision -> 20];
      sol = FindRoot[Last[ps[y0]][R], {y0, -1}, 
         Evaluated -> False][[1, 2]]; 
      Plot[Last[ps[sol]][r], {r, \[Epsilon], R}, AxesLabel -> {r, y'}, 
       PlotLabel -> 
        Grid[{{"Z", "g", "k2", "R"}, {Z0, g0, k0, R0}}, Frame -> All]]]
```

Two examples of using this code

```
Quiet[Table[
   p[800, g, 0.0002, 1.5], {g, 0.02, 0.06, .02}]] // AbsoluteTiming

Quiet[Table[
   p[800, .02, 0.0002, R], {R, 1.2, 1.7, .1}]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: Thank you so much, What is this method doing exactly? also, what is p1 and p ?

Comment: Can I do this in one step 'Quiet[Table[
   p[800, g, 0.0002, R], {g, 0.02, 0.06, .02}, {R, 1.2, 
    1.7, .1}]] // AbsoluteTiming' .?

Comment: p and p1 are the figures y and y', respectively, as the solution of the problem with the selection of parameters indicated at the top of each of the figures. You can use tables with any combination of parameters, but I checked only two of them.