# Need help in plotting a function with two variables in ODE

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics

The solution of this ODE was given in [this link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/182752/combined-parametricndsolvevalue-with-do-loop)

Here I am asking, if `L` is a function of `tot, g, Z` and `tot` depends on `Z` and `g`, which means I need to solve the ODE for each value of `Z` and `g` to get `tot` and then pass it to `L` function, after that Plot `L`.
I am not sure should I use `ContourPlot` or somethings els.
Help please.

```
p[Z0_, g0_, k0_, R0_] := 
  Block[{Z = Z0, 
         g = Rationalize[g0, 0],
         k2 = Rationalize[k0, 0],
         ϵ = 10^-4, 
         R = Rationalize[R0, 0]},
    ps = 
      ParametricNDSolveValue[
        {y''[r] + 2 y'[r]/r == k2 Sinh[y[r]], 
         y[ϵ] == y0, y'[ϵ] == 0, 
         WhenEvent[r == 1, y'[r] -> y'[r] + Z g]}, 
        {y, y'}, {r, ϵ, R}, {y0}, 
        Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", 
        WorkingPrecision -> 20];

sol = FindRoot[Last[ps[y0]][R], {y0, -1}, Evaluated -> False][[1, 2]];       
tot = 4 π sol NIntegrate[r^2  Exp[-First[ps[sol]][r]], {r, 0, R}];
L= Z/g*tot;

ContourPlot[L, {g, 0.02, 0.06}, {Z, 500, 800}]]

Quiet[
  Table[p[Z, g, 0.0002, 1.5], {g, 0.02, 0.06, .02},{Z, 500, 800, 200}]]
```

Comment: There is a missing `]` in your code

Comment: Also, the call to `Plot` has too many arguments.

Comment: @bbgodfrey well I need to vary both  'g' and 'Z' . From that I can study the behavior of `L` as function of these two variables . I do not know should I use `plot` or `CountorPlot` , or else.  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The desired contour plot can be obtained as follows.  Begin with a slight modification to the code in the question.

```
p[Z0_, g0_, k0_, R0_] := Block[{Z = Z0, 
  g = Rationalize[g0, 0], k2 = Rationalize[k0, 0], ϵ = 10^-4, R = Rationalize[R0, 0]}, 
  ps = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y''[r] + 2 y'[r]/r == k2 Sinh[y[r]], y[ϵ] == y0, y'[ϵ] == 0, 
    WhenEvent[r == 1, y'[r] -> y'[r] + Z g]}, {y, y'[R]}, {r, ϵ], R}, {y0}, 
    Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", WorkingPrecision -> 20];
  sol = FindRoot[Last[ps[y0]], {y0, -1}, Evaluated -> False][[1, 2]];
  tot = 4 π sol NIntegrate[r^2 Exp[-First[ps[sol]][r]], {r, ϵ, R}];
  L = Z/g*tot]
```

Specifically, `{y, y'}` is replaced by `{y, y'[R]}` to save a bit of time, because the value of `y'` is needed only at `r = R`; a corresponding change is made in the first argument  of `FindRoot`; the lower bound of `NIntegrate` is set to `ϵ`, because `ps` is undefined for smaller values of `r`; and `ContourPlot` is removed from within the definition of `p`.

The desired contour plot then is

```
ContourPlot[Quiet[p[Z, g, 0.0002, 1.5]], {g, 0.02, 0.06}, {Z, 500, 800}, 
    PlotPoints -> {5, 4}, MaxRecursion -> 1, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
    FrameLabel -> {g, Z}, ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, 15}]
```

[image]

which takes about two minutes on my computer.  The plotting can, however, be parallelized with equal resolution using

```
DistributeDefinitions[p];
tab = ParallelTable[Quiet[p[Z, g, 0.0002, 1.5]], {Z, 500, 800, 50}, {g, 0.02, 0.06, .005}];
ListContourPlot[tab, DataRange -> {{.02, .06}, {500, 800}}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
    FrameLabel -> {g, Z}, ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, 15}]
```

which produces the same plot in 37 seconds.  (My computer has six processors.)  Finally, the table requested in the question is

```
Table[Quiet[p[Z, g, 0.0002, 1.5]], {g, 0.02, 0.06, .02}, {Z, 500, 800, 200}]
(* {{-3.41941*10^11, -6.80714*10^11}, {-3.51627*10^11, -6.9574*10^11}, 
    {-3.55499*10^11, -7.0144*10^11}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks so much @bbgodfrey. You did what I want exactly.  Question, as you see the ode is very stiff and I wondering if you are a ware of a method to estimate the initial guess in the `findroot` ? if I want to do a `DO loop` instead of Block, do know how to write the code (just want the value of L without plotting?

Comment: @aluuzz  Despite the error message, I do not think that the equation is particularly stiff.  Instead, for `y0` sufficiently negative, `y'[r]` approaches negative infinity for `r < R`.  As a consequence `r = R` cannot be reached from `r = ϵ`, and `ParametricNDSolve` encounters a singularity in `y'[r]` when trying to do so.  Thus, if the initial guess for `FindRoot` produces an error message, try a more positive guess.  Also, to produce tables of `L` try using `Table` and `p`, as in the last code block in my answer.  I  hope this helps.  Remember that the computation is likely to be slow.

Comment: Thanks @bbgodfrey! I know using `Table` and `p` as in the last code block will produce tables of `L`. However, I am interested in doing a computation with `Do loop` . I know there are a two parameters in the loop `g` and `Z`, and`might need to use a `nest loop`.  Suppose there are three functions `L` `H` `Q`, and I want to know the value of these functions at a specific value of `Z` and `g`. It would be easy in `Do` rather than `Table`. Do you know how to achieve this?

Comment: @aluuzz  Would a `Do` that calls `p` work?

Comment: It would, but how the syntax would be?

Comment: @aluuzz  Similar to the definition of `p` in my answer, but with the final line containing all the quantities you want; e.g., `{L = …, H = …, Q = …}`.

Comment: Ok! @bbgodfrey The `Do` would be `Do[Quiet[p[Z, g, 0.0002, 1.5]],{g, 0.02, 0.06, .02}, {Z, 500, 800, 200}]`? Am I right?

Comment: @aluuzz  Yes, that is correct, but `Table` would work just as well, and `ParallelTable` better.

Comment: Last things (; @bbgodfrey If I want to print the value of `tot`. Is this right: `Do[Quiet[p[Z, g, 0.0002, 1.5],Print[NumberForm[tot,  5]]],{g, 0.02, 0.06, .02}, {Z, 500, 800, 200}]`

Comment: @aluuzz  `Print` works; just try it.  But consider `AppendTo` instead, because it stores the output, so that you can use later.  Again, `Table` is simpler.

Comment: Could we help me in this?@bbgodfrey.  I am trying to vary `g` ,`Z` and `k2` by `Table[Quiet[p[Z, g, k2, 1.5]], {g, 0.01, 0.03, .02}, {Z, 1000, 4000, 500},{k2, 0.0002, 100, 50}]` but I did not get a solution. The ODE becomes so stiff

Comment: For `k2 > 5`, `y0 = -1` is a bad initial guess.  For instance, with `k2 = 10`, ` -.45 < y0 < -.08` is required, approximately.

Comment: Thanks @bbgodfrey. How do you now a good from bad initial guess? Is there a method to know that?

Comment: A bad guess causes `ParametricNDSolve` to fail for `r < R`. The problem is finding good guesses by some method other than random tries. I tried a few ideas early this morning, and one of them worked.  I posted it to your new question.

Comment: Q.@bbgodfrey you said use : `Similar to the definition of p in my answer, but with the final line containing all the quantities you want; e.g., {L = …, H = …, Q = …}` .Ok, but how to plot these function by `ContourPlot`?

Comment: Plot each in turn by the same method used in my answer for a `ContourPlot`.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, you are simply missing a `]` at the end of

`Plot[L, {g, 0.02, 0.06}, {Z, 500, 800}]]`

```
p[Z0_, g0_, k0_, R0_] := 
 Block[{Z = Z0, g = Rationalize[g0, 0], 
   k2 = Rationalize[k0, 0], \[Epsilon] = 10^-4, 
   R = Rationalize[R0, 0]}, 
  ps = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y''[r] + 2 y'[r]/r == k2 Sinh[y[r]], 
     y[\[Epsilon]] == y0, y'[\[Epsilon]] == 0, 
     WhenEvent[r == 1, y'[r] -> y'[r] + Z g]}, {y, 
     y'}, {r, \[Epsilon], R}, {y0}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", 
    WorkingPrecision -> 20];
  sol = FindRoot[Last[ps[y0]][R], {y0, -1}, Evaluated -> False][[1, 
     2]];
  tot = 4 \[Pi] sol NIntegrate[r^2 Exp[-First[ps[sol]][r]], {r, 0, R}];
  L = Z/g*tot;
  Plot[L, {g, 0.02, 0.06}, {Z, 500, 800}]]

 Quiet[Table[p[Z, g, 0.0002, 1.5], {g, 0.02, 0.06, .02}, {Z, 500, 800, 200}]]
```

Adding your missing bracket and then running `Quiet[stuff]`

Gives:

[image]

Comment: Your code not working ? I do not know HOW you got these plots????!!!!!!. And `L` can not take this shape!

Comment: The plots you show were not produced by the code in your answer.  How did you obtain them?

Comment: @bbgodfrey do you have any clue for solving my problem?

Comment: @aluuzz it appears i had something already initialized that let me plot. I cannot reproduce those plots either. I’ll attempt to resolve.