# Help in finding a good guesses for ode

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics

This problem solved in [1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/210296/need-help-in-plotting-a-function-with-two-variables-in-ode) by @bbgodfrey. However, when I changed the parameters, the ode becomes very stiff and I did not know which best guess I need to use for `y0`. I am looking for :

```
 ParallelTable[Quiet[p[Z, g, k2, 1.5]], {g, 0.01, 0.03, .02}, {Z, 1000, 4000, 500},{k2, 0.0002, 100, 50}]
```

Does anyone know a method to estimate a good initial guess? I do not want to just put a random tries every time. I tried
`-.1 < y0 < -.08`,but did not find a solution.

Here is my code:

```
p[Z0_, g0_, k0_, R0_] := Block[{Z = Z0, 
      g = Rationalize[g0, 0], k2 = Rationalize[k0, 0], ϵ = 10^-4, R = Rationalize[R0, 0]}, 
      ps = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y''[r] + 2 y'[r]/r == k2 Sinh[y[r]], y[ϵ] == y0, y'[ϵ] == 0, 
        WhenEvent[r == 1, y'[r] -> y'[r] + Z g]}, {y, y'[R]}, {r, ϵ], R}, {y0}, 
        Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", WorkingPrecision -> 20];
      sol = FindRoot[Last[ps[y0]], {y0, -1}, Evaluated -> False][[1, 2]];
      tot = 4 π sol NIntegrate[r^2 Exp[-First[ps[sol]][r]], {r, ϵ, R}];
      L = Z/g*tot]
DistributeDefinitions[p];
tab = ParallelTable[Quiet[p[Z, g, 0.0002, 1.5]], {Z, 500, 800, 50}, {g, 0.02, 0.06, .005}];
ListContourPlot[tab, DataRange -> {{.02, .06}, {500, 800}}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
    FrameLabel -> {g, Z}, ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, 15}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply stated, a "good" initial guess for `y0` in `FindRoot` is one for which `ParametricNDSolve` can integrate the ODE in the question from `r = ϵ` to `r = R` without errors.  For the parameter ranges used in question [210296](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/210539/1063), `-1` or any other negative number roughly in the range `{-5, 0}` worked well.  The present question, however, introduces a much wider set of parameters, some of which accommodate only tiny ranges for the initial guesses.  However, if the desired guess can be bracketed in `y0`, then the bracketed region can systematically be shrunk until a valid guess is obtained.

Specifically, `fy` in the code block below begins by bifurcating, `yc = (yl + yu)/2`, the bracketing region, and checks by means of `tst = First[ps[yc]]["Domain"][[1, 2]]` to determine whether `ParametricNDSolve` is able to integrate the ODE all the way to `R` for `y0 = yc`.  If so, `fy` has found a good `y00`, which it `Throw`s to `p` and terminates.  Otherwise, it takes advantage of the fact that `y'[tst]` is negative when `yc` is more negative than the band of good guesses and is positive when `yc` is more positive than the band of good guesses in order to reduce the size of the bracketing region by a factor of two, after which the process is iterated until a good guess is found.  Typically, less than ten iterations are required to find `y00`.

```
p[Z0_, g0_, k0_, R0_] := Block[{Z = Z0, g = Rationalize[g0, 0], k2 = Rationalize[k0, 0], 
        ϵ = 10^-4, R = Rationalize[R0, 0], yl = -8, yu = 0, ps, fy, y00, sol}, 
    ps = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y''[r] + 2 y'[r]/r == k2 Sinh[y[r]], y[ϵ]] == y0, 
        y'[ϵ] == 0, WhenEvent[r == 1, y'[r] -> y'[r] + Z g]}, {y, y'}, {r, ϵ, R}, 
        {y0}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", WorkingPrecision -> 20];
    fy := (Do[yc = (yl + yu)/2; 
        tst = First[ps[yc]]["Domain"][[1, 2]];
        If[tst == R, Throw[yc]]; 
        If[Last[ps[yc]][tst] > 0, yu = yc, yl = yc], {i, 50}]; yc);
    y00 = Which[R == First[ps[yl]]["Domain"][[1, 2]], yl, 
        R == First[ps[yu]]["Domain"][[1, 2]], yu, True, Catch[fy]];
    sol = FindRoot[Last[ps[y0]][R], {y0, y00}, Evaluated -> False][[1, 2]];
    L = Z/g 4 π sol NIntegrate[r^2 Exp[-First[ps[sol]][r]], {r, ϵ, R}]]
```

Applying `p` to the parameter set introduced by the present question yields.

```
DistributeDefinitions[p];
ParallelTable[Quiet[p[Z, g, k2, 1.5]], {Z, 1000, 4000, 500}, {g, 0.01, 0.03, .02}, 
    {k2, 0.0002, 100, 50}]

(* {{{-1.36776*10^12, -14119.8}, {-1.422*10^12, -16956.}}, 
    {{-3.13388*10^12, -33652.5}, {-3.2242*10^12, -40906.5}}, 
    {{-5.62603*10^12, -63057.8}, {-5.79668*10^12, -75910.8}}, 
    {{-8.84774*10^12, -102510.}, {-9.06488*10^12, -122341.}}, 
    {{-1.2798*10^13, -152604.}, {-9.58419*10^10, -179866.}}, 
    {{-1.74782*10^13, -213431.}, {-6.31954*10^10, -248535.}}, 
    {{-2.2886*10^13, -287387.}, {-5.70976*10^10, -327845.}}} *)
```

The computation requires about ninety seconds on my six-processor computer, with only a small portion of that time used to obtain initial guesses.  Note that the iteration over `Z`, which has most elements, is placed at the leftmost position to maximize the advantage of parallelization.  Placing it as in the question increases the runtime to four minutes.

In closing, I would make two points.  First, the "guess finder function", `fy`, fails if `{yl, yu}` does not bracket at least part of the band of good guesses.  If `fy` does not converge to a good guess, sufficiently decreasing `yl` should solve the problem.  Second, `WorkingPrecision` may need to be increased for some parameters to improve accuracy.

Comment: Nice work @bbgodfrey, Why you need to use `WhenEvent[Abs[y[r]] > 10^5, "StopIntegration"]`?

Comment: I really appreciate what have you done @bbgodfrey. I tried to understand what you have done here, but I did not figure out it. Could you please explain what is the name of iteration and why `yl+yu/2`. I am sorry for this question but I have no experience in iterative methods :  `fy := (Do[yc = (yl + yu)/2; 
        tst = First[ps[yc]]["Domain"][[1, 2]];
        If[tst == R, Throw[yc]]; 
        If[Last[ps[yc]][tst] > 0, yu = yc, yl = yc], {i, 50}]; yc);
    y00 = Which[R == First[ps[yl]]["Domain"][[1, 2]], yl, 
        R == First[ps[yu]]["Domain"][[1, 2]], yu, True, Catch[fy]];`

Comment: @aluuzz  No reason to be sorry for your question.  I added an explanation to the answer.  By the way, the second `WhenEvent`, which you asked about earlier, turned out not to have much value, so I deleted it.  I also listed the variables used inside `Block` in its internal variables list, so that they would not interfere with any variables with the same names outside `p`.  Typically, not necessary but good practice.